# Passing user defined TABLE type to stored Oracle function

Tags: sql, oracle, eclipselink, nativequery

I have an oracle function defined as:

```
FUNCTION SELECTINBOX (FA_FROMUSERLIKE IN PKGSMSTYPES.MAXVARCHAR2_T DEFAULT NULL , 
        FA_INBOXOWNER IN PKGSMSTYPES.MAXVARCHAR2_T, 
        FA_A_URGENCY IN G_INTARRAY_TBL DEFAULT NULL , 
        FA_PAGENO IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1
) RETURN G_SMSNOTES_TBL;
```

where G_INTARRAY_TBL is defined as,

```
create or replace
TYPE G_INTARRAY_TBL AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

I am building the query using eclipselink. The query works fine if I hardcode G_INTARRAY_TBL as null in the query string but if I try to pass a List of BigDecimals to it, I get an error,

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
Error Code: 17004
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your code for your query.

You need to use a PLSQLStoredFunctionCall (@NamedPLSQLStoredFunctionQuery) for this.  You also need to mirror the PLSQL TABLE type with a VARRAY type.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PLSQLStoredFunction